# i want count point records from mysql db by id user using php to json endcode

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

[THIS IS MY DATABASE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6lUY.png)

This is my php for get record from mysql db. Help me to count point
 from database by user id. I implemented my project using android studio
Can you help me how to count record using mysql query?

```
<?php 
require_once"../konmysqli.php";
$respon = array();

if (isset($_GET["kode_pengguna"])) {
$kode_pengguna = $_GET['kode_pengguna'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM `$tbinvoice` WHERE `kode_pengguna` = 
'$kode_pengguna'";
$jum=getJum($conn,$sql);
if ($jum>0) {
$d=getField($conn,$sql);
$record = array();
$record["kode_pengguna"] = $d["kode_pengguna"];
$record["point"] = $d["point"];
$record["kode_invoice"] = $d["kode_invoice"];
$record["nomor_invoice"] = $d["nomor_invoice"];

$respon["sukses"] = 1;
$respon["record"] = array();

array_push($respon["record"], $record);
$respon["pesan"] = "$jum record";
echo json_encode($respon);
} else {
$respon["sukses"] = 0;
$respon["pesan"] = "0 record";
echo json_encode($respon);
}

} else {
$respon["sukses"] = 0;
$respon["pesan"] = "? lengkapi data";
echo json_encode($respon);
}
?>

<?php

function getJum($conn,$sql){
$rs=$conn->query($sql);
$jum= $rs->num_rows;
$rs->free();
return $jum;
}

function getField($conn,$sql){
$rs=$conn->query($sql);
$rs->data_seek(0);
$d= $rs->fetch_assoc();
$rs->free();
return $d;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the row quantity in a query you can use:

```
select count(*) from X_Table where X_Condition;
```